# GatsbyJS - Issue In Creating A Foreign Key @Link Back Reference

Tags: graphql, markdown, gatsby

I've been trying to link a list of categories housed in a JSON file to my blog posts in markdown format. I've been able to get as far as displaying linked categories when listing out my posts in GraphQL, but when trying to carry out a back-reference to list out posts linked to a category nothing gets returned.

My Category JSON file looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ASP.NET",
    "slug": "ASPNET"
  },
  {
    "name": "Azure",
    "slug": "Azure"
  },
  ...
]
```

The `gatsy-node.js` file contains a `createSchemaCustomization` function where the link between category and post is made:

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;

  const typeDefs = `
    type MarkdownRemark implements Node {
      frontmatter: Frontmatter
    }
    
    type Frontmatter {
      categories: [Category] @link(by: "slug")
    }
    type Category implements Node {
      allMarkdownRemark: [MarkdownRemark] @link(by: "frontmatter.categories.slug", from: "slug")
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

The foreign-key link is based on the "slug" field.

As stated above, categories are being output correctly when listing out blog posts as you can see below:

```
"allMarkdownRemark": {
      "edges": [
         {
          "node": {
            "id": "e785d80a-f6d8-5c74-bf32-6b29c6715319",
            "fields": {
              "slug": "/Blog/2020/11/22/Preserving-Digital-Memories",
              "prefix": "2020-11-22"
            },
            "frontmatter": {
              "title": "Preserving Digital Memories",
              "date": "2020-11-22T12:20:00Z",
              "categories": [
                {
                  "name": "Hardware & Tech",
                  "slug": "Hardware-Tech"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Random Thoughts",
                  "slug": "Random-Thoughts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "eeafca41-c439-5dd1-a17e-f77d30bb1653",
            "fields": {
              "slug": "/Blog/2020/11/17/Setting-A-Radio-Alarm-On-A-Google-Nest-Hub-The-Long-winded-Approach",
              "prefix": "2020-11-17"
            },
            "frontmatter": {
              "title": "Setting A Radio Alarm On A Google Nest Hub: The Long-winded Approach",
              "date": "2020-11-17T22:30:00Z",
              "categories": [
                {
                  "name": "Hardware & Tech",
                  "slug": "Hardware-Tech"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
       ]
    }
```

But when I'm trying to do the other way round - listing out posts that reside inside categories, nothing gets returned:

```
"allCategory": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "name": "ASP.NET",
          "slug": "ASPNET",
          "allMarkdownRemark": null
        },
        {
          "name": "Azure",
          "slug": "Azure",
          "allMarkdownRemark": null
        },
        {
          "name": "C#",
          "slug": "C",
          "allMarkdownRemark": null
        }
      ]
    }
```

As you can see, all the `allMarkdownRemark` objects return null.

I am perplexed as to why this is the case.

Any help is appreciated.